# Excel-formula-analysis state machine

Tags: python, excel, state-machine

This is one of my first useful scripts. I run it on a highlighted text selection within Notepad++, but I've provided a sample formula and commented out the Scintilla-specific references.

I'm a rank amateur: Am I using good idiom? Is my approach to a state machine sensible?

```
# input_text = editor.getSelText()
input_text = '=HLOOKUP(TablePeriods[[#Headers],[YearMonth]],TablePeriods[[#All],[YearMonth]],MATCH([@Date],INDIRECT("TablePeriods[[#All],["&[@Account]&"]]"),-1))'

# initialize the state table
EVENTS = 11
STATES = 7
state_table = [[[0,0] for x in range(EVENTS)] for x in range(STATES)]

# event list and corresponding state table
event_list =     [ "\"",   "&",   "(",   ")",   ",", "\n\r\t ",    "[",   "]",   "{",   "}"    ] # last event is anything that doesn't match one of the other actions
state_table[0] = [[1,0], [0,1], [5,0], [0,3], [0,4],     [0,5],  [2,0], [0,0], [6,0], [0,0], [0,0]] # normal state
state_table[1] = [[0,0], [1,0], [1,0], [1,0], [1,0],     [1,0],  [1,0], [1,0], [1,0], [1,0], [1,0]] # double-quote comment
state_table[2] = [[2,0], [2,0], [2,0], [2,0], [2,0],     [2,0],  [3,0], [0,0], [2,0], [2,0], [2,0]] # inside bracketed table reference
state_table[3] = [[3,0], [3,0], [3,0], [3,0], [3,0],     [3,0],  [4,0], [2,0], [3,0], [3,0], [3,0]] # inside double-bracketed table reference
state_table[4] = [[4,0], [4,0], [4,0], [4,0], [4,0],     [4,0], [-1,0], [3,0], [4,0], [4,0], [4,0]] # inside triple-bracketed table reference (I don't think this exists)
state_table[5] = [[1,2], [0,2], [5,2], [0,0], [0,2],     [0,5],  [2,2], [0,2], [0,2], [0,2], [0,2]] # found left-paren; only wrap and insert if not empty, like =row()
state_table[6] = [[6,0], [6,0], [6,0], [6,0], [6,0],     [6,0],  [6,0], [6,0], [6,0], [0,0], [6,0]] # inside curly-braced array

# initialize the state, parenthesis depth, and output text
current_state = 0
paren_depth = 0
output_text = ""

# define the tab and new line characters
TAB_CHAR = "\t"
NEW_LINE = "\r\n"

for z in input_text:
    for a in range(len(event_list)):
        if z in event_list[a]:
            takeaction = state_table[current_state][a][1]
            current_state = state_table[current_state][a][0]
            break
    else:
        takeaction = state_table[current_state][-1][1] # this sets takeaction to the value when the test character does not match any event
        current_state = state_table[current_state][-1][0] # this sets current_state to the value when the test character does not match any event
    if current_state == -1:
        current_state = 5 # -1 is an error and should be handled with some sort of error operation
    if takeaction == 0: # just pass the characters along
        output_text += z
    elif takeaction == 1: # place character at same depth as only one on line
        output_text += NEW_LINE + TAB_CHAR*paren_depth + z + NEW_LINE + TAB_CHAR*paren_depth
    elif takeaction == 2: # previous character was a left paren and this one is not a right-paren
        paren_depth = paren_depth + 1
        output_text += NEW_LINE + TAB_CHAR*paren_depth + z
    elif takeaction == 3: # character is a right paren not immediately following a left paren
        paren_depth = paren_depth - 1
        output_text += NEW_LINE + TAB_CHAR*paren_depth + z
    elif takeaction == 4: # character is a comma, so start a new line at the paren depth
        output_text += z + NEW_LINE + TAB_CHAR*paren_depth
    elif takeaction == 5: # strip whitespace from the input outside of quotes
        pass
    else:
        pass # should raise error, since the state table includes more actions than are defined

# editor.replaceSel(output_text)
print(output_text)
```

My code, without sample, is on [Gisthub](https://gist.github.com/Fluffums/9550351#file-npp-py-analyzeexcelformula).

Comment: I just found this question that seems related and that I intend to look through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492980/what-are-the-best-python-finite-state-machine-implementations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Josay's suggestions are good; I only mention where I have a different idea:

- The way you create `state_table` is a bit of an anti-idiom, but in this case I see a benefit too: seeing the number in `state_table[2] = ...` improves the readability of the state machine as a whole. However, initializing the variable to the nested list comprehension is redundant. I suggest changing `state_table` to a dictionary. The rest of the code works as is if you use

  ```
  state_table = {}
  ```
- Use `zip` to iterate over two lists in parallel. Instead of this

  ```
  for a in range(len(event_list)):
      if z in event_list[a]:
          takeaction = state_table[current_state][a][1]
          current_state = state_table[current_state][a][0]
  ```

  do this (using also sequence unpacking)

  ```
  for event, next_state in zip(event_list, state_table[current_state]):
      if z in event:
          current_state, takeaction = next_state
  ```
- ...except in this case don't. Instead, avoid the inner loop altogether by first creating a mapping

  ```
  char_to_event = {char: i for i, event_chars in enumerate(event_list) 
                   for char in event_chars}
  ```

  which allows you to replace the loop (including the else clause) with this:

  ```
  event = char_to_event.get(z, -1)
  current_state, takeaction = state_table[current_state][event]
  ```
- You can avoid the lengthy `elif` chains with dictionary lookup and string formatting. Given these dictionaries

  ```
  action_table = {
      0: "{z}",
      1: "{newline}{indent}{z}{newline}{indent}",
      2: "{newline}{indent}{z}",
      3: "{newline}{indent}{z}",
      4: "{z}{newline}{indent}"
  }
  depth_table = {
      2: +1,
      3: -1
  }
  ```

  the `if takeaction ... elif` statement can be replaced with this:

  ```
  paren_depth += depth_table.get(takeaction, 0)
  output_text += action_table.get(takeaction, "").format(
      z=z, 
      indent=TAB_CHAR*paren_depth,
      newline=NEW_LINE)
  ```

Comment: Nice trick! I didn't see that coming.

Comment: Sweet. Now, why shouldn't I go a step further and eliminate the `event = ...` line: `current_state, takeaction = state_table[current_state][char_to_event.get(z, -1)]`

Comment: @Dane You can do that too. It's a choice between an extra line+variable and a longer line.

Comment: @Dane Added a way to skip the long `elif` chain.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [list unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to transform :

```
        takeaction = state_table[current_state][a][1]
        current_state = state_table[current_state][a][0]
```

into the more concise :

```
        current_state, takeaction = state_table[current_state][a]
```

. Also, it shows that the type you should be using to convey `current_state` and `takeaction` should probably be something more like a tuple than like a list.

---

The pythonic way to loop is not to use `range` and `len` but just to go through your iterable with `for i in my_iterable:`. If you do need the index, [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#enumerate) is what you need.

```
   for a in range(len(event_list)):
        if z in event_list[a]:
            takeaction = state_table[current_state][a][1]
            current_state = state_table[current_state][a][0]
```

becomes :

```
for i,event in enumerate(event_list):
    if z in event:
        current_state, takeaction = state_table[current_state][i]
        break
```

---

Remove whatever code is not needed.

```
elif takeaction == 5: # strip whitespace from the input outside of quotes
        pass
    else:
        pass # should raise error, since the state table includes more actions than are define
```

is roughly the same as nothing. If you want to ensure the value is correct, you can use [assert](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement).

---

From [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id40) :

> For example, do not rely on CPython's efficient implementation of
>   in-place string concatenation for statements in the form a += b or a =
>   a + b. This optimization is fragile even in CPython (it only works for
>   some types) and isn't present at all in implementations that don't use
>   refcounting. In performance sensitive parts of the library, the
>   ''.join() form should be used instead. This will ensure that
>   concatenation occurs in linear time across various implementations.

---

Remove duplicated logic :

```
        takeaction = state_table[current_state][a][1]
        current_state = state_table[current_state][a][0]
```

and

```
   takeaction = state_table[current_state][-1][1] # this sets takeaction to the value when the test character does not match any event
    current_state = state_table[current_state][-1][0] # this sets current_state to the value when the test character does not match any event
```

are quite similar and probably can be factorised out.

---

Do not repeat yourself (bis) : you do not need to define the state table twice. Just do it once and for all and everything should be ok :

```
state_table = [
    [(1,0), (0,1), (5,0), (0,3), (0,4), (0,5), ( 2,0), (0,0), (6,0), (0,0), (0,0)], # normal state
    [(0,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), ( 1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0)], # double-quote comment
    [(2,0), (2,0), (2,0), (2,0), (2,0), (2,0), ( 3,0), (0,0), (2,0), (2,0), (2,0)], # inside bracketed table reference
    [(3,0), (3,0), (3,0), (3,0), (3,0), (3,0), ( 4,0), (2,0), (3,0), (3,0), (3,0)], # inside double-bracketed table reference
    [(4,0), (4,0), (4,0), (4,0), (4,0), (4,0), (-1,0), (3,0), (4,0), (4,0), (4,0)], # inside triple-bracketed table reference (I don't think this exists)
    [(1,2), (0,2), (5,2), (0,0), (0,2), (0,5), ( 2,2), (0,2), (0,2), (0,2), (0,2)], # found left-paren; only wrap and insert if not empty, like =row()
    [(6,0), (6,0), (6,0), (6,0), (6,0), (6,0), ( 6,0), (6,0), (6,0), (0,0), (6,0)], # inside curly-braced array
]
```

---

**Final result :**

This is what my code is like at the end. I am too lazy to change the string concatenations for a better solution. Also, I'm still not quite happy with the multiple `if` statements but I have nothing better to suggest at the moment.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# input_text = editor.getSelText()
input_text = '=HLOOKUP(TablePeriods[[#Headers],[YearMonth]],TablePeriods[[#All],[YearMonth]],MATCH([@Date],INDIRECT("TablePeriods[[#All],["&[@Account]&"]]"),-1))'

# initialize the state table
# event list and corresponding state table
event_list =     [ "\"",   "&",   "(",   ")",   ",", "\n\r\t ", "[",   "]",   "{",   "}"    ] # last event is anything that doesn't match one of the other actions
state_table = [
    [(1,0), (0,1), (5,0), (0,3), (0,4), (0,5), ( 2,0), (0,0), (6,0), (0,0), (0,0)], # normal state
    [(0,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), ( 1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0)], # double-quote comment
    [(2,0), (2,0), (2,0), (2,0), (2,0), (2,0), ( 3,0), (0,0), (2,0), (2,0), (2,0)], # inside bracketed table reference
    [(3,0), (3,0), (3,0), (3,0), (3,0), (3,0), ( 4,0), (2,0), (3,0), (3,0), (3,0)], # inside double-bracketed table reference
    [(4,0), (4,0), (4,0), (4,0), (4,0), (4,0), (-1,0), (3,0), (4,0), (4,0), (4,0)], # inside triple-bracketed table reference (I don't think this exists)
    [(1,2), (0,2), (5,2), (0,0), (0,2), (0,5), ( 2,2), (0,2), (0,2), (0,2), (0,2)], # found left-paren; only wrap and insert if not empty, like =row()
    [(6,0), (6,0), (6,0), (6,0), (6,0), (6,0), ( 6,0), (6,0), (6,0), (0,0), (6,0)], # inside curly-braced array
]

# initialize the state, parenthesis depth, and output text
current_state = 0
paren_depth = 0
output_text = ""

# define the tab and new line characters
TAB_CHAR = "\t"
NEW_LINE = "\r\n"

for z in input_text:
    for i,event in enumerate(event_list):
        if z in event:
            break
    else:
        i = -1
    current_state, takeaction = state_table[current_state][i]
    if current_state == -1:
        current_state = 5 # -1 is an error and should be handled with some sort of error operation
    if takeaction == 0: # just pass the characters along
        output_text += z
    elif takeaction == 1: # place character at same depth as only one on line
        output_text += NEW_LINE + TAB_CHAR*paren_depth + z + NEW_LINE + TAB_CHAR*paren_depth
    elif takeaction == 2: # previous character was a left paren and this one is not a right-paren
        paren_depth = paren_depth + 1
        output_text += NEW_LINE + TAB_CHAR*paren_depth + z
    elif takeaction == 3: # character is a right paren not immediately following a left paren
        paren_depth = paren_depth - 1
        output_text += NEW_LINE + TAB_CHAR*paren_depth + z
    elif takeaction == 4: # character is a comma, so start a new line at the paren depth
        output_text += z + NEW_LINE + TAB_CHAR*paren_depth
    else:
        assert(takeaction == 5) # strip whitespace from the input outside of quotes
        pass # should raise error, since the state table includes more actions than are defined

# editor.replaceSel(output_text)
print(output_text)
```

Comment: This is terrific. Thank you! `enumerate()` was definitely something I've been looking for, but didn't know how to find it (or even that it existed). Also, I should probably think of tuples more. On that note: shouldn't the whole state_table become nested tuples? Also the event_list?

Comment: Reusing Raymond Hettinger, I usually try to go for "Loopy lists and structy tuples". In your case, state_table and event_list are things you are iterating on so list makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps, but on the other hand, my state_table should not be altered, so the immutable quality of tuples is perhaps more appropriate for the whole thing. Either way, I've learned several valuable lessons here.

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708510/python-list-vs-tuple-when-to-use-each different people will give you different answers, some based on mutability, some based on the way you want to use your container (position has relevance).